# Parsing HTML data with lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I'm a beginner in coding and a friend of mine told me to use BeautifulSoup instead of htmlparser. After running into some problems I got a tip to use lxml instead of BeaytifulSoup because it's 10x better.

I'm hoping someone can give me a hint how to scrape the text I'm looking for.

What I want is to find a table with the following rows and data:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="website1.com">website1</a></td>
    <td>info1</td>
    <td>info2</td>              
    <td><a href="spam1.com">spam1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="website2.com">website2</a></td>
    <td>info1</td>
    <td>info2</td>              
    <td><a href="spam2.com">spam2</a></td>
</tr>
```

How do I scrape the website with info 1 and 2, without spam, with `lxml` and get the following results?

```
[['url' 'info1', 'info2'], ['url', 'info1', 'info2']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import lxml.html as LH

doc = LH.fromstring(content)
print([tr.xpath('td[1]/a/@href | td[position()=2 or position()=3]/text()')
       for tr in doc.xpath('//tr')])
```

The long XPath has the following meaning:

```
td[1]                                   find the first <td>  
  /a                                    find the <a>
    /@href                              return its href attribute value
|                                       or
td[position()=2 or position()=3]        find the second or third <td>
  /text()                               return its text value
```

Comment: You just made my day with a few lines of code. And thank you for the explanation. Actually all of the answers are great. I was learning about the xpath to get it with firebug. But his is much easier to find the first table row and process the data within. Thank you all again and merry x-mas :)

Answer (score 4):

I use the **xpath**: `td/a[not(contains(.,"spam"))]/@href | td[not(a)]/text()`

```
$ python3
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc = lxml.html.parse('data.xml')
>>> [[j for j in i.xpath('td/a[not(contains(.,"spam"))]/@href | td[not(a)]/text()')] for i in doc.xpath('//tr')]
[['website1.com', 'info1', 'info2'], ['website2.com', 'info1', 'info2']]
```

Comment: All the table rows are the same within the table. I'm using Python 2.7.2+. Within the table row I only want the first 3 and as result. So [['url(website1)', 'info1', 'info2'], ['url(website2)','info1', 'info2']]. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I think it can probably be safely assumed that the actual content will not contain the words spam. Although only @Trees can really tell us what aspects of the data are consistent.

Comment: @Acorn  changed to `contains(.,"spam")`. `spam` can be replace by patterns like `ad.website.com`.

Answer (score 4):

```
import lxml.html as lh

tree = lh.fromstring(your_html)

result = []
for row in tree.xpath("tr"):
    url, info1, info2 = row.xpath("td")[:3]
    result.append([url.xpath("a")[0].attrib['href'],
                   info1.text_content(),
                   info2.text_content()])
```

**Result:**

```
[['website1.com', 'info1', 'info2'], ['website2.com', 'info1', 'info2']]
```